# memory management concept behind initialization and declaration of integer in c#

Tags: c#, memory-management, integer

Stupid question but I just need to know about memory management concept of initialization and declaration of integer.
what is the difference in term of memory between two syntax.

```
private int a;

and 

private int a=0;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: None.

Long answer: all variables are initialized with default values by the CLR before returned to user defined code. Your field will be initialized with `0` anyway before you have any kind of access to it.

> **10.5.4 Field initialization**
>
> The initial value of a field, whether it be a static field or an
>   instance field, is the default value (§5.2) of the field’s type. It is
>   not possible to observe the value of a field before this default
>   initialization has occurred, and a field is thus never
>   “uninitialized”.

Answer (score 1):

in C# everything gets initialized one way or the other.

If this were C++ and you did the first one out in global space it would be actual garbage. but C# will either prevent you from using the variable until it is sure it has been initialized or it will initialize it itself.

As for the memory management side, integers might not be the best example. Integers aren't exactly "managed" in memory. They're just 4 bytes inside of a class instance that live or die along with the class living or dying. Now, if you're asking about say a reference value, then you can expect that when the class dies and it goes to clean itself up, C# is going to have it attempt to clean up everything that it has as a member, which may result in destructing another class's instance.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking frankly there is no difference between the two line in C#. All member variables are assigned with their default value if they were not initialized.

Please verify the two line as below:

```
private int a;
private int a1 = 0;

// Compare with default value.
Console.WriteLine(a1 == default(int));

// Compare both variables
Console.WriteLine(a1 == a);
```

Answer (score 1):

In c# all variables are initialized by default...
So you not need to initailized any variable.